# TextWatcher and seekBar issues

Tags: java, android

Hi I've never asked a question on here before I hope I'm doing this right. I'm trying to get the TextWatcher to work with three TextEditors but I can't figure out how to do it with what I have. I'm also pretty sure my seekBar is messed up, it should be displaying years not percentages and it kind of doesn't do anything when it slides. Any help would be appreciated, it's for a mortgage calculator app on android studio.

```
CODE

// MainActivity.java file
package com.example.mortgagecalculator;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable; // for EditText event handling
import android.text.TextWatcher; // EditText listener
import android.widget.EditText; // for bill amount input
import android.widget.SeekBar; // for changing the tip percentage
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener; // SeekBar listener
import android.widget.TextView; // for displaying text

import java.text.NumberFormat; // for currency formatting

// MainActivity class for the Tip Calculator app
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // currency and percent formatter objects
    private static final NumberFormat currencyFormat =
            NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    private static final NumberFormat percentFormat =
            NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();

    private double purchaseAmount = 0.0; // bill amount entered by the user
    private double downPaymentAmount = 0.0; // down payment entered by user
    private double interestRate = 1.0; // interest rate percentage entered by user
    private double duration = 0.15; // initial year duration

    private double annualInterestRate;
    private int numberOfYears;
    private double loanAmount;

    private TextView purchasePriceTextView; // shows purchase price
    private TextView downPaymentAmountTextView; // shows down payment
    private TextView interestRateTextView; // shows interest rate
    private TextView durationTextView; // shows years of loan

    private TextView loanTextView; // shows loan amount
    private TextView monthlyTextView; // shows calculated monthly payment amount

    // called when the activity is first created
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // call superclass onCreate
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // inflate the GUI

        // get references to programmatically manipulated TextViews
        purchasePriceTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewPurchasePrice);
        downPaymentAmountTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewDownPaymentAmount);
        interestRateTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewInterestRate);
        durationTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewDuration);

        loanTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLoan);
        monthlyTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewMonthlyPayment);
        loanTextView.setText(currencyFormat.format(0));
        monthlyTextView.setText(currencyFormat.format(0));

        // set editTextPurchasePrice's TextWatcher
        EditText editTextPurchasePrice =
                (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPurchasePrice);
        editTextPurchasePrice.addTextChangedListener(editTextWatcher);

        // set editTextDownPayment's TextWatcher
        EditText editTextDownPaymentAmount =
                (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextDownPaymentAmount);
        editTextDownPaymentAmount.addTextChangedListener(editTextWatcher);

        // set editTextInterestRate's TextWatcher
        EditText editTextInterestRate =
                (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextInterestRate);
        editTextInterestRate.addTextChangedListener(editTextWatcher);

        // set seekBarYear's OnSeekBarChangeListener
        SeekBar seekBarYear =
                (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarYear);
        seekBarYear.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekBarListener);
    }

    // calculate and display tip and total amounts
    private void calculate() {

        // format percent and display in textViewDuration
        durationTextView.setText(percentFormat.format(duration));

        // calculate the monthly interests and loanAmount
        double monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate / 1200;
        double monthlyPayment = loanAmount * monthlyInterestRate / (1 -
                (1 / Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterestRate, numberOfYears * 12)));
        //return monthlyPayment

        double loanAmount = purchaseAmount - downPaymentAmount;

        // display tip and loanAmount formatted as currency
        loanTextView.setText(currencyFormat.format(loanAmount));
        monthlyTextView.setText(currencyFormat.format(monthlyPayment));
    }

    // listener object for the SeekBar's progress changed events
    private final OnSeekBarChangeListener seekBarListener =
            new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                // update percent, then call calculate
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                                              boolean fromUser) {
                    duration = progress / 100.0; // set percent based on progress
                    calculate(); // calculate and display tip and total
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { }
            };

    // listener object for the EditText's text-changed events
    private final TextWatcher editTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        // called when the user modifies the purchase price amount
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int before, int count) {
            try { // get bill amount and display currency formatted value
                purchaseAmount = Double.parseDouble(s.toString()) / 100.0;
                purchasePriceTextView.setText(currencyFormat.format(purchaseAmount));
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // if s is empty or non-numeric
                purchasePriceTextView.setText("");
                purchaseAmount = 0.0;
            }

            try {
                downPaymentAmount = Double.parseDouble(s.toString()) / 100.0;
                downPaymentAmountTextView.setText(currencyFormat.format(downPaymentAmount));
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // if s is empty or non-numeric
                downPaymentAmountTextView.setText("");
                downPaymentAmount = 0.0;
            }

            try {
                interestRate = Double.parseDouble(s.toString()) / 100.0;
                interestRateTextView.setText(percentFormat.format(interestRate));
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // if s is empty or non-numeric
                interestRateTextView.setText("");
                interestRate = 0.0;
            }

            calculate(); // update the tip and total TextViews
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(
                CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
    };
}
```